# Proving/Disproving the existence of a specific set under ZFC axiom system.

Tags: set-theory

For the last few days I'm having trouble with proving the following statements in set-theory (under ZFC):

Let $a$ be an ordinal,

(1) Prove the existence of the set of all cardinalities ($k$) which satisfy: $2^{k} = 2^{ℵ_a}$

(2) Prove that the set of all sets ($A$) which satisfy: $2^{|A|} = 2^{ℵ_a}$ does not exist.

(Note: both questions require to rely only on the axioms of ZFC (although simple terms and basic arguments which stems from the axioms are generally ok))

---

For problem (1) my first instinct was that the only cardinality which satisfy such equation is ${ℵ_a}$ because if some *other* cardinality will do then it will disprove the generalized continuum hypothesis (which is known to be 'undisprovable'), therefore the set we are looking for is {$ℵ_a$} which obviously exists.

For problem (2) my intuition was to notice that if we assume the existence of the set of all sets with cardinality ${ℵ_a}$ (which is, at least, a subset of the set in question) then by looking at its union we will get the set of all sets which is obviously a contradiction.

Yet I'm unsure of both of my 'solutions' (specifically the first one), is there any way to solve those 2 questions in a correct, cleaner, more 'axiomatic' way?

- BTW: this is my first question on StackExchange so let me know if i did anything wrong.

Comment: It’s expected here that your question show some evidence of your independent effort to solve the problem.  Please **edit the question*8 to include this information.

Comment: @RobertShore Thank you for your feedback, i have updated my post. ill be very happy to hear your opinion about my questions and solution-attempts.

Comment: The fundamental limitation on sets is that they can't be too "big."  To prove that the collection of objects satisfying a certain formula is in fact a set, it works to prove that they all must be contained in something you already know to be a set, because then you can use Comprehension.  To prove that a collection can't be a set, use the assumption of its existence as a set to show that something you know to be a proper class would be a set.  For example, do you already know that there is no set of all cardinals?

Comment: There can be models of $\sf ZFC$ in which the set you are looking for in (1) is not $\{\aleph_{\alpha}\}$. For example, it can be that $2^{\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_1}$. One thing you know for sure is that $2^{\aleph_{\alpha}} = \aleph_{\beta}$ for some ordinal $\beta$. So for such $\kappa$’s we have $\kappa < \aleph_{\beta}$, so the collection of such $\kappa$’s cannot be “too big”.

Comment: @Tan great answer, it’s very clear now, thank you

Comment: For (2), if $B=\{A:2^{|A|}=2^{\aleph_{\alpha}}\}$ exists then $\forall x\,\forall b\in B\,(\{x\}\times b\in B\} .$ Then, since $B\ne\emptyset,$ this implies  (usingthe Kuratowski ordered pair $(a,b)=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}\,)$ that $\forall a\,(a\in\bigcup \bigcup B\} $ but then by Comprehension $\{a\in\bigcup \bigcup B: a\not\in a\}$ is the set of all sets that are not members of themselves, & hence Russell's Paradox.

Comment: Ran out of editing time. In my previous comment I meant to use $c$, not $b$, in the def'n of ordered pair to avoid confusion with $b\in B.$